# ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined variable: file_style

Tags: php, kohana

Не находит стили и скрипты.

```
<head>
    <title><?= $site_name ?> | <?= $page_title ?></title>
    <? foreach ($styles as $file_style): ?>
        <?= html::style($file_style) ?>
    <? endforeach ?>
    <? foreach ($scripts as $file_script): ?>
        <?= html::script($file_script) ?>
    <? endforeach ?>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
</head>
```

---

```
class Controller_Index extends Controller_Common {

    public $template = 'v_common';        // Базовый шаблон

    public function before() {
        parent::before();

        $this->template->styles[] = 'media/css/style.css';
        $this->template->scripts[] = 'media/js/reg.js';

        $this->template->block_header = View::factory('v_header');
        $this->template->block_center_left  = View::factory('v_center');
        $this->template->block_center_right = View::factory('v_right'); 
        $this->template->block_footer = View::factory('v_footer');

    }

}
```

Пишет

> `ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined variable: file_style`

причем раньше все работало.

Comment: Посмотрите во вью, что находится в массиве $styles

Comment: что значит "раньше"? раньше, чем что? попытайтесь вспомнить, какие действия предшествовали тому, что "всё сломалось"

Comment: Покажите  $styles и класс html